# Arc 10.2.2 crashes when adding query layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, sql, query, oracle-dbms

I'm trying to add a query layer from an Oracle database into a blank 10.2.2. map.   I enter the query, validate, finish, and the software thinks for a second and then just winks out.  No error message, no nothing.

One of my co-workers can perform the exact same query layer and a table shows up in his blank map.  The only difference is that we are working in different paths on the network drive and we have some slightly different software installed on our computers,  (I have InfoMaker, for example).  I am able to perform the queries from InfoMaker and Oracle Developer, just not ArcGIS.

We both have the same model of computer (Dell 7010) and the same Zen image installation of the software.  I deleted normal.mxt.

Comment: Can you try using a different map? Maybe start with an empty mxd?

Comment: Yes, I tried starting with a blank .mxd.   It still crashed.

Comment: what does the query look like? can you post the sql statement?

Comment: Sure.  here it is:
Select  Cast (EDATA.FP_LATITUDE_LONGITUDE.FP_PLACE_ID as Int) as objectid, Cast (EDATA.FP_LATITUDE_LONGITUDE.FPL_LAT_LONG_ID as Int) as LLID, EDATA.FP_LATITUDE_LONGITUDE.FPL_DATA_SOURCE from EDATA.FP_LATITUDE_LONGITUDE where EDATA.FP_LATITUDE_LONGITUDE.FP_PLACE_ID < 500

Answer (score 0):

I have determined that the problem in my case most likely has to do with my database account profile, not ArcGIS.  The problem only occurs on certain tables. When a different user logged into the DB from my machine they were able to perform the query without crashing the software.  The DB Admins have been contacted.